# Javascript `this` not working as I thought?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, this

I'm adapting a pretty basic js function into a class. Anyway, basically it just creates a floating container 
above the main page. I'm aware it's incomplete, but I'm in the middle of typing it up, and keep getting caught out when attempting to call the close() function. Firefox returns a `this.sdiv` is undefined. I'm confused as to how this can be the case when close() is Pop's method and sdiv is defined in the first line of the Pop class?

```
function Pop( wpx,hpx ){

  Pop.prototype.sdiv;
  Pop.prototype.shadow;
  Pop.prototype.pdiv;

  // start with the invisible screen, which
  // covers the main page
  this.sdiv = document.createElement("DIV")
  this.sdiv.className = "popScreen";
  this.sdiv.id = "popScreen";
  // this screen covers the full document, so 
  // base dimensions on the document size
  this.sdiv.style.width = document.body.clientWidth + "px";
  this.sdiv.style.height = document.body.clientHeight + "px"; 
  document.body.appendChild( this.sdiv );

  // attach drop shadow
  this.shadow = document.createElement("DIV");
  this.shadow.className = "popShadow";
  this.shadow.style.width = wpx + "px";
  this.shadow.style.height = hpx + "px";
  this.shadow.style.left = ( ( window.innerWidth / 2 ) - ( wpx / 2 )  ) + "px";
  this.shadow.style.top = ( ( window.innerHeight / 2 ) - ( hpx / 2 ) ) + "px";
  document.body.appendChild( this.shadow );

  this.pdiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  this.pdiv.className = "pop";
  this.pdiv.id = "pop";
  this.pdiv.style.position = "absolute";
  this.pdiv.style.width = wpx + "px";
  this.pdiv.style.height = hpx + "px";
  this.shadow.appendChild( this.pdiv );

  // bind an event to the screen div so that when it is clicked
  // the Pop dialogue is closed and the user is return to the main page
  $("div#popScreen").click( function( ){
    Pop.prototype.close( );
  } );

  Pop.prototype.go = function( url, method, data ){ 
    if( method == null )
      $("div#pop").load( url );
  }

  Pop.prototype.close = function( ){
      this.sdiv.parentNode.removeChild( this.sdiv );
      this.shadow.parentNode.removeChild( this.shadow );
      this.pdiv.parentNode.removeChild( this.pdiv );
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hint: Since you are defining the prototypes in the constructor, they are redefined every time you create a new object. You should move all prototype declarations to be outside the definition of the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `Pop.prototype.close()` to close all `Pop` instances. Instead, for each instance of `Pop` that you have created with the `new` operator, you need to call `popInstance.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in javascript works [very differently](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) to this in oo languages.

The error you have is here:

```
  Pop.prototype.close = function( ){
      this.sdiv.parentNode.removeChild( this.sdiv );
      this.shadow.parentNode.removeChild( this.shadow );
      this.pdiv.parentNode.removeChild( this.pdiv );
  }
```

In that function `this` is probably [referring to the window](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-why-the-this-keyword-breaks) (set a breakpoint and have a look in firebug)

Perhaps something along these lines will work.

```
 var parent = this;
 Pop.prototype.close = function(){
      parent.sdiv.parentNode.removeChild( this.sdiv );
      parent.shadow.parentNode.removeChild( this.shadow );
      parent.pdiv.parentNode.removeChild( this.pdiv );
  }
```